# I tried to enable conservation mode in Ubuntu

Tags: dell, laptop, battery-charging-threshold

I've been trying to enable conservation mode in my laptop in Ubuntu my laptop is Dell G15 5520 ,any one know how and i need a GUI for that not a command
for anyone don't know the conservation mode :Conservation mode in some  laptops will stop the battery from charging above 60% to improve the lifespan of the battery.

Comment: It depends on if the laptop support this feature.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Linux utility for this. If BIOS supports it, it can be enabled either in BIOS, or by writing to a system register.

Comment: @Pilot6 I thought `tlp` can do this by setting the [*stop charge threshold*](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html) but indeed it is hardware vendor specific.